# Identify A Red Book Glimpsed On Subway, "City Of..."

Tags: identification-request

Help me ID a book, seen on subway:

Book in new condition, undersized hardcover, red cloth cover.  No dustjacket in evidence, but probably originally had one. Endpapers clearly had maps on them, probably regional maps, not city maps. Title appeared to be "City Of *something*", where the "something" had an S somewhere in the middle.  Title appeared solely on spine.  Title font was blocky, with triangular serifs, similar to the font used in the "Blades In The Dark" logo.

Many thanks...

EDIT: Further notes: I saw it today, in Boston.  The book is in English, and appeared to be fiction.  Page count appeared to be somewhere around 200, possible higher.

Comment: Hello Jon W. and welcome to Literature.SE! Thank you for including lots of details for your book identification question. If you can think of any others, such as some listed [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/guidelines-for-good-story-id-questions/779#779), please feel free to add them. Thanks!

Comment: City of Glass or another in the Mortal Instruments series by Cassandra Clare? City of Bastards by Andrew Shvarts? City of Brass by S.A. Chakraborty? City of Joy by Dominque Lapierre?

Answer (score 2):

It's been identified as *City Of Bastards* by Andrew Shvarts.  -JW

Comment: Hey Jon, glad you managed to find the book! Please could you [edit] this answer to include more detail about **how this book matches your description**, so that any future readers of your question can see whether or not it solves their problem too? We have some [site guidance](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/840/17) on what a good story-ID answer should look like. Thanks!